# What is the cheapest way of flying with two slightly overweight bags on an American Airlines flight to India?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, british-airways, american-airlines, code-share

I'm flying from **St. Louis, USA** to **Chennai, India.**. My luggage is around 4 kilos more than acceptable when checking-in two bags.

What would be the fee to check-in these two slightly overweight bags (each 2 kilos over)? Is there a better way to avoid this charge?

I'm still a Bronze BA Executive Club (this is a BA-codeshare flight) with a bunch of Avios in my kitty. Can I use my Avios against the extra weight charges?

Comment: Have you tried logging into your booking to see what the extra charge would be? I'm unfamiliar how to do it on AA, but [BA online lets you check the cost, and pay less in advance of doing it at the airport](http://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/baggage-essentials/extra-overweight-baggage)

Comment: 8lbs isn't that much.  Can you just move something to your carry on?

Comment: @pnuts thx; BA lets you put in the overage and see how much you'd be charged, and I agree with Johns-305, 4 Kgs, remove, carry on, post, leave behind, discard

Comment: @pnuts I agree; 25kg in each bag, check in very early and AA may just okay it since it's a BA codeshare, OP is a BA Exec Club member and is en route to India. My link was to respond to the Q on the amount of the charges.

Comment: He'll get one checked bag free based on his oneworld status, so that might complicate things. It's a real toss-up. At only 4kg though, I would just leave something behind, or carry it on, or post it.

Comment: They're unlikely to be overlooked since any bag over 23kg has to have a heavy bag tag attached.

Comment: From my experience, they'll allow it if it's just a few pounds over (I got away with 52). However, I'm not sure about 4lbs in each bag because it depends on the agent.

Comment: If they go to charge you, rearrange your items so only one bag is overweight.

Answer (score 2):

I have "escalated" the "Can I use my Avios against the extra weight charges?" question to flyertalk. This is the [answer](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/27517549-post2.html):

> No, not directly, though if you have a BA ticket you can use Avios to upgrade to a higher cabin to gain the increased baggage allowance, subject - of course - to availability. In some situations this may be a good idea.
>
> But you can't currently use Avios to directly pay for luggage. However this is a study going on at the moment to greatly expand the use of Avios, to include paying for seat fees, luggage and other ancillary services. Buy on Board is an example of this happening.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to purchase a used jacket with big, bulky pockets and stuff the 4KG of items into the pockets....if the agents want to charge you extra.

I have seen some people wear 4 shirts on a plane.  At first I thought it was to stay warm, but they were wearing two coats when they got off the plane.